# GROUP BY in datatable on two columns with sum of third column using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am searching for a LINQ query for which input and output datatables are as below -

```
Name    Code    count
-------------------------
User1   q1  2

user1   q2  2

user2   q2  1

user2   q3  3

user1   q1  2



Name    Code    Count
-----------------------
User1  |    q1   |  4
User1  |    q2   |  2
User1  |    q3   |  0
User2  |    q1   |  0
User2  |    q2   |  1
User2  |    q3   |  3
```

i.e. I want sum of count for distinct set of codes for each Name, in result table, it showing (user1, q3,0) because there is no record of q3 for user1 in input datatable, Please help in this regard, Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new { Name = row.Field<string>("Name"), Code = row.Field<string>("Code") });

var table2 = table.Clone(); // empty table with same schema
foreach (var x in query)
{
    string name = x.Key.Name;
    string code = x.Key.Code;
    int count = x.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Count"));
    table2.Rows.Add(x.Key.Name, x.Key.Code, count);
}
```

**Edit**: if you instead want to modify the original table and sum the count per each name-code group, use this approach which uses a `Dictionary` as lookup:

```
var nameCodeCountLookup = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new { Name = row.Field<string>("Name"), Code = row.Field<string>("Code") })
    .ToDictionary(ncGrp => ncGrp.Key, ncGrp => ncGrp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Count")));
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    string Name = row.Field<string>("Name");
    string Code = row.Field<string>("Code");
    row.SetField("Count", nameCodeCountLookup[new { Name, Code }]);
}
```

However, i don't know why your result table contains this row:

```
User1  |    q3   |  0
```

There is no name-code combination User1+q3   in the original table.

Comment: Hi tim, thanks for your reply, but 1st code is throwing error - "Specified cast is not valid" when binding to table2

Comment: @user3240893: then the column `Count` is not an `int` column but (i guess) a string column. Change that.

Comment: User1  |    q3   |  0 ; i want to show count (can be 0) for all distinct code in input table

Comment: @user3240893: note that i've edited my first approach. I think that's much simpler. According to your last comment, i'll have a look later.

Comment: Count = codeGroup.Sum(r => Convert.ToInt64(r["code"])), i used this, now its showing result but not as required.

Comment: I want that there should be same set of codes for each name, ie if there are maximum 5 codes for user1 and 2 codes for user2 & user3 then it  should show 5 codes for user1, user2 & user3 in result with count 0 if code is not in input table

Comment: @user3240893 you should look on data type stored in column `code`. If it's Int64, then you can simply cast to long: `r => r.Field<long>("Code")`

Comment: `Convert.ToInt64(r["code"]))` should be incorrect since it contains values like `"q1"`, do you mean `count` instead?  So is it a numeric value then you should edit your question and provide correct sample data. You need the maximum-code of all name-groups first, but the maximum code can only be calculcated if it's a numerical field.

Comment: Still not able to get desired result

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you looking for:

```
  var result =
            new DataTable().Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                .Select(p => new {User = p[0], Q = p[1], Value = (double) p[2]})
                .GroupBy(p => new {p.User, p.Q})
                .Select(p => new {User = p.Key.User, Q = p.Key.Q, Total = p.Sum(x => x.Value)})
                .ToList();
```

Or almost same, but you can do it too:

```
   var result =
            new DataTable().Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                .Select(p => new 
                          {
                              User = p.Field<string>("column1Name"), 
                              Q = p.Field<string>("column2Name"), 
                              Value = p.Field<double>("column3Name")
                          })
                .GroupBy(p => new {p.User, p.Q})
                .Select(p => new {User = p.Key.User, Q = p.Key.Q, Total = p.Sum(x => x.Value)})
                .ToList();
```